"An unexpected error occurred while performing review" when approving Staging Ground post in "Major Changes"
Previously, I requested Major Changes to this post trying to get the author to ask for a more minimal reproducer.
As the author said they weren't able to reduce it more and I think it looks like a reasonable question (Perfect is the enemy of good), I wanted to approve the post I was previously requesting changes on a few minutes before. Doing so resulted in me getting this message:

According to the devtools, I am getting the following response from the server:
{"Success":false,"ValidationFailure":false,"Message":"An unexpected error occurred while performing review","WasReviewedSincePageLoad":false,"WasEditedSincePageLoad":false,"HasUserReachedDailyReviewLimit":false,"IsLockedForReview":false}

When I click on "Submit" again, I am getting told the post has been reviewed in the meantime.

Refreshing the page and submitting my review again results in me getting the An unexpected error occurred while performing review error again.
My actions are also visible in the review history:

Is this caused by some length limit of 16384 characters or similar?
Update
I was able to publish it by using the "Minor Edits" option and then approving it.
This also happened here, here and here but (at least in the first case) the "Minor Edits" option didn't work in that case.
I reported a similar (possibly the same) issue during the beta (link requires beta access) but it was marked as status-norepro as it only happened very few times and (as far as I know) never after my bugreport until the beta ended.
